# My Update manager is not showing the latest version of ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates

I am currently having ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Edit your question and paste the result of these commands: `sudo uname -a` and `sudo lsb_release -a`

Answer (score -1):

As per your statement, if you want to upgrade to next version (12.04 ?) of ubuntu using update manager just type this command in terminal (or hit alt+f2 to run as a program)

```
$ update-manager -d
```

It will pop up update manager with the option to upgrade to next version of ubuntu on top.